# Sparklyr slice_max(with_ties = FALSE) returning extra rows

Tags: r, dplyr, databricks, sparklyr

I am using sparklyr on databricks to query some delta tables.

I expect the below code to return 5 rows, but it returns all rows, as if `slice_max` is only doing `arrange()` and no slicing.

```
db %>% 
  group_by(col_a, col_b) %>%
  count() %>%
  slice_max(n, 5, with_ties = FALSE) %>%
  data.frame() %>% display()
```

edit: I tried `slice_head()` and `slice()` but got an error - apparently those operations are not supported on database backends.

Comment: Can you try with `df %>% group_by(col_a, col_b) %>% count(sort = TRUE) %>% slice_head(5) %>% data.frame() %>% display()`

Comment: @akrun I tried that first but got `slice_head() is not supported on database backends`

Comment: Then you may use `slice(1:5)` (if it is supported) instead of `slice_head`

Comment: @akrun hahah I had just updated the question because of your previous comment; I had also tried slice, but it is also not supported :(

Comment: Not sure which one is supported :(.  Perhaps `%>% do(head(., 5))`

Comment: wow i feel like we have the same thoughts XD i just tried `count(sort = TRUE) %>% data.frame() %>% head(5) %>% display()` and it did it successfully

Answer (score 1):

The answer is I did not ungroup() before slice_max() so I was asking for the top 5 rows per group, which is the whole dataset since I had already summarized by count. 
Working code:

```
db %>% 
  group_by(col_a, col_b) %>%
  count() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  slice_max(n, 5, with_ties = FALSE) %>%
  data.frame() %>% display()
```

Comment: this is much faster than do(head) since converting all the rows to data.table was slow for me